# Web Forms error message: "This is not scriptlet. Will be output as plain text"

Tags: asp.net, webforms

In my ASP .NET Web Forms I have the following declarative code:

```
<asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txtbox" CssClass='<%=TEXTBOX_CSS_CLASS%>' />
```

The constant TEXTBOX_CSS_CLASS is defined in a base class that the page's code-behind class inherits from:

```
public class MyPageBase : Page
{
    protected internal const string TEXTBOX_CSS_CLASS = "myClass";
}
```

The edit-time compiler however warns me that "This is not scriptlet [sic]. Will output as plain text".
True to its word, the css class is rendered as literally "<%=TEXTBOX_CSS_CLASS%>".

What does this error message mean and is there a workaround so I can still use a constant in a base class?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

You cannot use `<%= ... %>` to set properties of server-side controls.
Inline expressions `<% %>` can only be used at
aspx page or user control's top document level, but can not be embeded in
server control's tag attribute  (such as  `<asp:Button... Text =<% %> ..>`).

If your TextBox is inside a DataBound controls such as GridView, ListView .. you can use: `<%# %>` syntax. OR you can call explicitly `DataBind()` on the control from code-behind or  inline server script.

```
<asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txtbox" class='<%# TEXTBOX_CSS_CLASS %>' />
```

// code Behind file

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{     
        txtbox.DataBind();
}
```

ASP.NET includes few built-in expression builders that allows you to extract custom application settings and connection string information from the `web.config` file. Example:

- Resources
- ConnectionStrings
- AppSettings

So, if you want to retrieve an application setting named `className` from the `<appSettings>` portion of the `web.config` file, you can use the following expression:

```
<asp:TextBox runat="server" Text="<%$ AppSettings:className %>" />
```

However, above snippet isn't a standard for reading classnames from Appsettings.

You can build and use either your own Custom `ExpressionBuilders` or Use code behind as:

```
txtbox.CssClass = TEXTBOX_CSS_CLASS;
```

**[Check this link](http://haacked.com/archive/2006/11/29/Express_Yourself_With_Custom_Expression_Builders.aspx)** on building Custom Expression builders.
Once you build your custom Expression you can display value like:

```
<asp:TextBox Text="<%$ SetValue:SomeParamName %>"
    ID="setting" 
    runat="server" />
```

Answer (score 16):

The problem is that you can't mix `runat=server` controls with `<%= .. %>`code blocks. The correct way would be to use code behind: `txtbox.CssClass = TEXTBOX_CSS_CLASS;`.

Answer (score 9):

This will work.

Mark up

```
<asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txtbox" class='<%# TEXTBOX_CSS_CLASS %>' />
```

Code-behind

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        txtbox.DataBind();
    }
}
```

But its a lot cleaner to access the `CssClass` property of the `asp:TextBox` on `Page_Load`

Comment: where does the weird <%# syntax come from?

Comment: @spankmaster79: just read the above answer for a detailed explanation.