# Dynamic CssClass using inline tag

Tags: asp.net, css, tags, inline

Is there a way to dynamically set the css class name dynamically using the following construct:

`<asp:Panel ID="pDisplayMode" class="dynaClass<%= this.codeBehindVar )%>" runat="server">`

I tried this as well to no avail:
`<asp:Panel ID="pDisplayMode" CssClass="dynaClass<%= this.codeBehindVar )%>" runat="server">`

I realize that I can manipulate the CssClass in the code behind, however, I would like to keep it in the markup only, if possible.

Comment: This is probably what you are looking for, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18952849/web-forms-error-message-this-is-not-scriptlet-will-be-output-as-plain-text

Comment: Strangely, inline tag `<%# %>` does get processed, however in the final markup the css tag is completely missing.