# Parser Error Message

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, c#-4.0

---

### My asp.net code

---

```
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:tdfConnectionString2 %>" SelectCommand="select * from answer,users where question_id="<%=Session["qid"]%>" and answer.user_id=users.user_id"></asp:SqlDataSource>
    <asp:Repeater ID="Repeater2" runat="server" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1">
        <HeaderTemplate>
            <div class="container">
        </HeaderTemplate>
        <ItemTemplate>
           <div class="panel panel-primary">
               <div  class="panel-heading">

                   <h2 class="panel-title"><a href="Answer.aspx?qid=<%#Eval("question_id") %>"><asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" Text="Reply"></asp:Label></a></h2>
              </div><!--panel-heading-->
               <div class="panel-body">
                       <asp:Image ID="Image1" runat="server" ImageUrl='<%#Eval("uimg")%>' Height="100" Width="100" />
                   <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("answer_detail") %>'></asp:Label>
                   <br />
                   <asp:Label ID="Label4" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("username") %>'></asp:Label>
                   <br />
            </div><!--panel-heading-->
        </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:Repeater>
```

---

### When is browse the application

Server Error in '/' Application.

Parser Error

Description: An error occurred during the parsing of a resource required to service this request. Please review the following specific parse error details and modify your source file appropriately.

Parser Error Message: The server tag is not well formed.

Source Error:

> Line 28:      Line 29:     
>  Line 30:
>   "
>   SelectCommand="select * from answer,users where
>   question_id="<%=Session["qid"]%>" and
>   answer.user_id=users.user_id"> Line 31:
>    Line 32:
>
> Source File: /Admin/QuestionView.aspx    Line: 30

Version Information: Microsoft .NET Framework Version:4.0.30319; ASP.NET Version:4.0.30319.34212

Comment: You have repeated ", try ...question_id='<%=Session...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot use `<%= ... %>` to set properties of server-side controls. Inline expressions `<% %>` can only be used at aspx page or user control's top document level, but can not be embeded in server control's tag attribute (such as  `<asp:SqlDataSource... SelectCommand =<%= %> ..>`).

You can not use `<%=Session["qid"]%>` inside a control with `runat=server`. And that will not be evaluated as this is a server contro. You can set that value in code behind or page_load event.

You need to put following in page_load event.

`SqlDataSource1.SelectCommand = select * from answer,users where question_id=" + Session["qid"].ToString() + " and answer.user_id=users.user_id"`

`SqlDataSource1.ConnectionString = "<PUT_YOUR_Connectrin_String_Here>";`

Update `SqlDataSource1` as following in aspx.

`<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server"></asp:SqlDataSource>`

Already explained here - [Web Forms error message: "This is not scriptlet. Will be output as plain text"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18952849/web-forms-error-message-this-is-not-scriptlet-will-be-output-as-plain-text)

Comment: Same problem again and again arise..! :(

Comment: @sarfarazchohan, you also need to set `ConnectionString` property in code behind too!, and remove that from here. Also after setting that in code behind remove from aspx.

Comment: Thank you brother...! It is solved..! Thanx again it very help..! :)