# Contact a Resource file value with Required Field Validator

Tags: asp.net, webforms

I am currently doing the following in .aspx file.

```
Are you a member of <%= Project.My.Resources.XYZ%>
```

and it works perfectly well. But when I try to concatenate it like this

```
<asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="optDepartmental_RequiredFieldValidator" ControlToValidate="optDepartmental"
runat="server" ErrorMessage= " this is a test <%# Project.My.Resources.XYZ %>"
Display="Dynamic" ValidationGroup="AddUserValidationGroup" CssClass="validationerror"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
```

It doesn't work. I checked [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18952849/web-forms-error-message-this-is-not-scriptlet-will-be-output-as-plain-text)
Also tried using a hidden field but result is still the same:

"
    Display="Dynamic" ValidationGroup="AddUserValidationGroup" CssClass="validationerror">

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved it by adding everything on the server side:

```
RequiredFieldValidator1.ErrorMessage = "this is a test " + Project.My.Resources.XYZ
```

and left ErrorMessage property in the markup as blank.